# Why does Rust want Self to be Sized when implementing an associated const with an associated type?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
pub trait Trait {
  type Type;
  const CONST: Self::Type;
}

impl<T> Trait for T {
  type Type = u8;
  const CONST: u8 = 42;
}
```

My (incorrect?) understanding of Rust is that this code should work and that all `Sized` types should now implement `Trait` and have an associated type (`Type = u8`) and const (`CONST = 42`). Unsized types shouldn't implement this trait since `impl<T>` implicitly assumes `T` to be `Sized`.

However, when I try to [compile the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3386c356e537e91c36d4b1590e5ca8d9&version=nightly&mode=debug) I get the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the size for value values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:8:3
  |
8 |   const CONST: u8 = 42;
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `T`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types--sized>
  = help: consider adding a `where T: std::marker::Sized` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Trait` for `T`
```

My questions:

- Why does Rust think that `T` isn't `Sized` here? [Explicitly stating `T: Sized` doesn't help](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0accf2876da1658f427d70150a1e0f62&version=nightly&mode=debug).
- Let's pretend `T` isn't `Sized`. Why does Rust care whether `T` is sized or not here? Nothing depends on it, as far as I can tell (the associated type and const aren't related to `T`). Changing the code to `T: ?Sized` works, so clearly `T` being unsized isn't actually problematic.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46969) for it.

Comment: Did you mean to write `impl<T: Sized> Trait for T`? (This doesn't solve the problem but matches your problem description more)

Comment: @Tim `T: Sized` is redundant: [All type parameters have an implicit bound of `Sized`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html).

Comment: @kazemakase: Thanks! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Cornstalks "It's a bug" hardly makes for a good answer... but apparently it is the only one there is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46969), this appears to be a known bug that has been around at least since Rust 1.23 (longer, I suspect).

It is not clear what is causing the problem and when/if it will be fixed. There is only a rather vague hypothesis:

> I'm not familiar with the compiler internals, but **my hypothesis is that associated types and constants depending on a type parameter are not evaluated properly in the constant expression evaluator**. In this case, it's associated types that do not reduce well: `const VAL: Self::T = 5;` forces Rust to do some fancy type of computation at compile time in order to type check, but there's a bug in the code for such computations.

There are a few ways to work around the issue:

1. Specifying a concrete type in the trait:

   ```
   pub trait Trait {
       // type Type;  // no longer used
       const CONST: u8;
   }
   ```
2. Opting `T` out of `Sized`:

   ```
   impl<T: ?Sized> Trait for T {
       type Type = u8;
       const CONST: u8 = 42;
   }
   ```
3. Use a function instead of a constant (credit goes to @PeterHall):

   ```
   pub trait Trait {
     type Type;
     fn const_val() -> Self::Type;
   }

   impl<T> Trait for T {
     type Type = u8;
     fn const_val() -> Self::Type { 42 }
   }
   ```

Comment: As a workaround, can't you just use a function in the trait instead of a `const`? It should get inlined to the same thing.

Comment: @PeterHall You are right of course. Thank you for pointing out that oversight.